# Functions / methods logic and case use

Tags: java, function, methods, logic

I have a question that is not technical by itself but more of a clarification. I apologize if this is not the correct place to ask it and once I can have a concrete answer any admin can cancel it.

So, I am learning java and since I am starting to understand the use of functions/methods but I have nobody to talk to since I learn by myself at home, is it really at my own free will what type of method I should choose to make my calculations?

I mean, if I have to convert something or take data from the user or whatever, I can freely chose what type of method I want? It can be a void or int or String and then add whatever parameter(s) I want? Or, is it a rule of thumb of what is to be used and not.

I found tutorials on using methods but nowhere it says that you need to use this or that instead of that etc.

Thanks and best regards.

Comment: The type you need for any parameter/return depends on what you are trying to do, and what external expectations there are about your function/method.  Similarly, when you use a function/method written by someone else, you have to work with the types they wrote the method to use.

Comment: You choose based on what you want or need to do. If you need to sum two integers and get the result, you'll use a method that takes two integers and returns an integer. If you need to find the index of the first string that starts with A in a list, you'll use a method that takes a List<String> as argument and returns an integer.

Comment: thanks, now it makes absolute sense. So if I have to make the sum of 2 ints, i will chose an int type method using 2 parameters and pass the two ints that I want the sum to be. Then if I want to show a String, then I use a String type method and pass "x" parameters to process that string. Makes sense. Thank you very much!